# change border color on click

Tags: html, css

I have a menu consisting of 4 div boxes. I want the active box to have a red border, if another box is clicked the border is white and the border of the other box is red. Do I need JavaScript or is CSS enough?

[jsfiddel div](http://jsfiddle.net/CkwQU/)

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
margin: 10px;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
border: solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: You will probably need javascript, if only because `div`s are not clickable by default.

Comment: for click you'll need javascript yeh, hover is ok with css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For click you'll need JavaScript if you want to maintain the state, hover is OK with CSS.

You can use `div:active { /* style */ }` for a click and hold style but it will disappear after mouse up.

This is a quick way to do it with jQuery:

```
$('.box').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('border-color', 'lime');
});
```

Probably better to toggle a class though:

JS:

```
$('.box').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('myClickState');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.myClickState {
  border-color: lime;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function fnChangeBorder(boxId)

{document.getElementById(boxId).style.border = "solid #AA00FF";}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="A" onclick="fnChangeBorder('A')">Click here !!</div>
```

i chose A as a parameter because numbers won't work as a function parameters

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.box:focus{ border-color:#cd3232; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `:active` pseudo-selector to achieve this.

Try this:

```
.box:active {
    border-color: red;   
}
```

This, however, will not persist after you release the mouse.

It is also not supported in IE6.

Comment: But the border change will not persist after mouse up: http://jsfiddle.net/CkwQU/1/

Comment: No, it won't.  If the goal is to change the element permanently, he should be applying a class to that element using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this function:

http://jqueryui.com/addClass/

It shows how to apply the click event and change the CSS class. You would simply have to create a desired class with border color.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via jQuery ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt25J/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    if($('.active').length) {
      $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active').addClass('box');
    }      
    $(this).removeClass('box').addClass('active');     
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `:focus` CSS pseudo-class in lieu of `:active`.

Try this:

```
.box:focus {
    border-color: red;   
}
```

This should persist after the click event is completed.